# A local function named 's' is already declared... Why am I prompted this everytime I change the variable in the for loop?

Tags: c#, string, ascii

I have a scenario where the user will input a number that will be the multiplier for an image (the image isn't from a file it's just text on the console using special characters). It could be thought of as ASCII art but I didn't go the route of using ASCII values for this scenario. I instead am using multiple strings, and I want to only multiply specific characters within each string, where it will match the original scale of the original 'image', but bigger depending on what the user picks.

I've tried going down the ASCII route, but my code was pretty messy. I tried to make each line of the image a separate method, and call each of them through a parameter, but never got to the parameter part because I got confused on how I could change the specific characters like stated above.

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
string edgeBorder = "#================#";


            int multiplier;

            multiplier = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(multiplier);
            Console.WriteLine("Sure! Coming right up...");

            //Top layer of quilt  
            for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(edgeBorder + " ");
            }
                Console.Write("\n");
            //top half of quilt
            for (int line = 1; line <= 4; line++)
            {

                for (int s = 0, s < (8 - 2 * line) * multiplier; s++)
                { //s for space
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                    Console.Write("|" + " ");
                if (line == 1)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < 2 * multiplier; d++)
                    { //d for diamond
                        Console.Write("<>");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("<>");
                    for (int p = 0; p < 4 * multiplier * (line - 1); p++)
                    { //p for period
                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                    Console.Write("<>");
                }
                Console.Write(" " + "|");
                for (int s = 0, s < (8 - 2 * line) * multiplier; s++)
                { //s for space
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            //bottom half of quilt
            for (int line = 4; line >= 1; line--)
            {

                for (int s = 0, s < (8 - 2 * line) * multiplier; s++)
                { //s for space
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.Write("|" + " ");
                if (line == 1)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < 2 * multiplier; d++)
                    { //d for diamond
                        Console.Write("<>");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("<>");
                    for (int p = 0; p < 4 * multiplier * (line - 1); p++)
                    { //p for period
                        Console.Write(".");
                    }
                    Console.Write("<>");
                }
                Console.Write(" " + "|");
                for (int s = 0, s < (8 - 2 * line) * multiplier; s++)
                { //s for space
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            //bottom layer of quilt
            for (int i = 0; i < multiplier; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(edgeBorder + " ");
            }
        }
//I went a different route, and decided not to use an array, only issue is it
//keeps telling me 's' is already defined in the scope, but when I change it to
//something different it says the same exact thing
```

```
/*$================$
     | <><> |
   | <>....<> |
 | <>........<> |
|<>............<>|
|<>............<>|
 | <>........<> |
   | <>....<> |
     | <><> |
$================$

and be this if multiplied by 2
$================$ $================$
            | <><><><> |
           | <>........<> |
       | <>................<> |
    |<>........................<>|
    |<>........................<>|
       | <>................<> |
           | <>........<> |
             | <><><><> |
$================$ #================$
I tried putting this into the "what's expected but it wouldn't format properly*/
```

I'm expecting an 'image' to be shown in the console, that's at whatever scale the user wants it to be. I'm lost on how to implement my idea to the code.
I put the expected part in the code section, it wouldn't format properly.

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to see what rules you are using in the expected part.  I.e. how are you applying the scaling?  Its seems on the first line you duplicate the entire line, on line 2 you duplicate the <>, the lines after you duplicate the .... and then on the last two lines duplicate <> again and then the entire line.  if you could make it clear what you actually want to happen when you scale an image, you could then work out how to do that in code

Comment: The whole first line will multiplied as a whole, the second line the <><> will be multiplied, and on the 3rd, 4th, and 5th line, the …, will be multiplied.

Comment: It is, I'm just trying to figure out what function or route I can go about using to multiply just those specific characters, not trying to get anyone to solve the whole thing for me, just a push in the right direction, I've been stuck for way to long.

Comment: First store your strings to an array of strings. There is no other way to 'modify' a string, if you haven't stored it at all. At the end display all your strings, so the creation-computation-output parts are separated.

Comment: I went a different route, can someone explain to me why in the for loop, when s is initialized why it says 's' is already defined in the scope? I changed it to a different variable but it says the same thing, also it says the '<' in the test of the loop is incorrect which I'm confused about.

Answer (score 1):

## A. Inflate

### Algorithm

```
image_width = firstLine.Lenght;
for each line:
    if( first or last) 
      repeat with a space in between
    else 
      pad right until width == image_width
      repeat each air molecule (the dot) twice 
      ( pad left, pad right ) until width == image_width
```

### Code

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> Inflate(string[] lines, int scale, string air)
    {
        // image_width = firstLine.Lenght;
        // for each line:
        //     if( first or last) 
        //         repeat with a space in between
        //     else 
        //         pad right until width == image_width
        //         repeat each air molecule (the dot) twice 
        //         ( pad left, pad right ) until width == image_width
        
        var imageWidth = lines[0].TrimEnd().Length;
        return lines.Select((line, i) =>{
            if (i == 0 || i == lines.Length - 1)
                return string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(line.TrimEnd(), scale));
        
            line = line.PadRight(imageWidth, ' ');
            line = line.Replace(air, string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(air, scale)));
            while (line.Length < imageWidth * scale) line = " " + line + " ";
            return line;
        });
    }
    private static string Inflate(string input, int scale, string air)
        => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Inflate(
            input.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), scale, air));
```

#### Test code

```
// I Maually removed '/*' from the input   
// Please note that the first line ends with a space, 
// but this space trimmed and is not considered part of the image 
string input = @"$================$ 
     | <><> |
   | <>....<> |
 | <>........<> |
|<>............<>|
|<>............<>|
 | <>........<> |
   | <>....<> |
     | <><> |
$================$";

Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine(Inflate(input, air: ".", scale: 2));
Console.WriteLine(Inflate(input, air: ".", scale: 3));
Console.WriteLine(Inflate(input, air: ".", scale: 4));
```

#### Output

Notes:

1. The images don't contain the spaces between the repeated header and footer, and your example output has spaces, but these spaces make the images asymmetrical, so I didn't includ them.
2. Your test image changes `| <><> |` to `| <><><><> |`, and this alogorithm doesn't. It could be modified to do that. It could also be extended to not have gaps so that air (`.`) doesn't escape, but that's for another day.

```
$================$
     | <><> |
   | <>....<> |
 | <>........<> |
|<>............<>|
|<>............<>|
 | <>........<> |
   | <>....<> |
     | <><> |
$================$
$================$$================$
              | <><> |
          | <>........<> |
      | <>................<> |
   |<>........................<>|
   |<>........................<>|
      | <>................<> |
          | <>........<> |
              | <><> |
$================$$================$
$================$$================$$================$
                       | <><> |
                 | <>............<> |
           | <>........................<> |
      |<>....................................<>|
      |<>....................................<>|
           | <>........................<> |
                 | <>............<> |
                       | <><> |
$================$$================$$================$
$================$$================$$================$$================$
                                | <><> |
                        | <>................<> |
                | <>................................<> |
         |<>................................................<>|
         |<>................................................<>|
                | <>................................<> |
                        | <>................<> |
                                | <><> |
$================$$================$$================$$================$
```

## B. Multiply the atoms

This is not exactly what you want, but it may be good enough.

```
    var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            lines.Select( l => new string(l.SelectMany(ch => Enumerable.Repeat(ch, scale)).ToArray())));
```

## Test

### Code

```
   string input = @"/*$================$
     | <><> |
   | <>....<> |
 | <>........<> |
|<>............<>|
|<>............<>|
 | <>........<> |
   | <>....<> |
     | <><> |
$================$";

    Console.WriteLine(input);

    var lines = input.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int scale = 2;

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine($"Scale : {scale}");
    Console.WriteLine("");

    var newLines  = 
            lines.Select( l => new string(l.SelectMany(ch => Enumerable.Repeat(ch, scale)).ToArray()));

    var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,newLines);

    Console.WriteLine(output);
```

### Output

```
/*$================$
     | <><> |
   | <>....<> |
 | <>........<> |
|<>............<>|
|<>............<>|
 | <>........<> |
   | <>....<> |
     | <><> |
$================$

Scale : 2

//**$$================================$$
          ||  <<>><<>>  ||
      ||  <<>>........<<>>  ||
  ||  <<>>................<<>>  ||
||<<>>........................<<>>||
||<<>>........................<<>>||
  ||  <<>>................<<>>  ||
      ||  <<>>........<<>>  ||
          ||  <<>><<>>  ||
$$================================$$
```